# Find child element of list item

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the troublesome function. I can not correctly locate the nested `UL` element:

```
function showContentAgency(id){
  $.post("assets/includes/contentAgency.php?id=id", {id: id}, function(data){
    $(this).parent().find("ul").html(data).show();
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
  });
}
```

Here's the click function:

```
$("ul.top-level").on("click", "ul.top-level li.agency a", function (event) {
    var numbs = $(this).attr("href").match(/id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
    $("ul.top-level li a").removeClass("nav-active");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
    showContentAgency(numbs);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

My HTML appears as so:

```
<ul class="top-level" style="display: block; ">
    <li class="agency"><a href="contentAgency.php?id=6" class="">Agency Name</a>
    <ul>
        <!--Content in here -->
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all inside success handler of `$.post` `this` do points to its own execution context. Next is you have to pass the dom element to `showContentAgency` method using which you can find the required `ul` element. Try this.

```
function showContentAgency(id, elem){
   $.post("assets/includes/contentAgency.php?id=id", {id: id}, function(data){
       $(elem).addClass("nav-active").parent().find("ul").html(data).show();
   });
}


$("ul.top-level").on("click", "ul.top-level li.agency a", function (event) {
    var numbs = $(this).attr("href").match(/id=([0-9]+)/)[1];
    $("ul.top-level li a").removeClass("nav-active");
    $(this).addClass("nav-active");
    showContentAgency(numbs, this);
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside `$.post`, `this` is not the element, it's the XHR object, I think.

Try to pass `this` to `showContentAgency` also.

```
function showContentAgency(id, ele){
  $.post("assets/includes/contentAgency.php?id=id", {id: id}, function(data){
    $(ele).parent().find("ul").html(data).show();
    $(ele).addClass("nav-active");
  });
}
```

And then:

```
showContentAgency(numbs, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `showContentAgency` function inside a handler, or is it by itself? If it is by itself, then `this` will refer to the window object, and `$(this)` will not return anything meaningful, and `$(this).parent()` will not do anything useful.

Maybe, in the click handler, you should replace the line `showContentAgency(numbs);` with `showContentAgency.call(this, numbs);`.

Comment: Inside the `$.post` this would still not be what you want.  You'd still need to assign it to a variable.